# How to set Paperclip :default_url according User gender and asset style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Through [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1040091) script I can get default url for paperclip with user **gender**. But I want to get :style too. Someone know how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default way of doing this:

```
#Assuming you default images are stored in app/assets/images/somedirectory

has_attached_file :attachment, default_url: :some_function

def some_function
   "somedirectory/:style/:class/#{self.gender}.png"
end
```

or using lambda:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, default_url: lambda{|attachment| "somedirectory/:style/:class/#{attachment.instance.gender}.png" }
```

Tested in Rails 4.

Comment: You are right, I added this to paperclip gem a long time ago and almost forgot ;D. Checkout: http://goo.gl/mQFaE5