# Get style parameter in dynamic default_url-block as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Assume I have two models, items and categories, where one category has_many items and one item belongs_to one category. Now both models can have images (managed with paperclip).

But if there is no image assigned with the item-model, I would like to show the image of the associated model, meaning of the category-model. I did this by changing the default_url of the item model to a dynamic lambda-based one:

```
has_attached_file :image, default_url: -> (attach) {attach.instance.category.image.url(...)}
```

But the problem is, I don't know how to find out, which style was orignally wanted. I have to pass the original style to the image.url-call. Is it possible to assign the wanted style to the passed attach-object so I can acccess it in my lambda?

As an alternative solution, I could return the "scoped url" as the result from the default_url-block, meaning a url which is not the final url as it still contains any needed "style" placeholders (e.g. "/the/path/to/my/image/**:style**/image.png?..."). Paperclip will then fill in the correct style (mentioned here: [Dynamic use of :default_url in Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784224/dynamic-use-of-default-url-in-paperclip)). But how is it possible to get this "base url" with its placeholders via model.image.url?

(My current solution is attach.instance.category.image.url(:thumb).gsub("/thumb/", "/:style/"), but thats kind of dirty..)

Comment: `attach.instance.category.image.url(:thumb).gsub("/thumb/", "/:style/")` is not perfect but it works for now. Thanks!