# Paperclip dynamic url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a Rails ActiveModel Product with a Paperclip `image attachment` column that needs to get it's `image.url` from 2 sources. One is an old S3 bucket/CloudFront, other is our new S3 bucket/CloudFront. They have completely different credentials.

If the `instance Product.image_file_name` is containing "old:" I want the URL to be something like `cloudfront_url/products/file_name`, if it doesn't - it should use the new S3 bucket/CloudFront. Upload is going to happen only on the new S3 bucket, but it'll fallback on the old one if `image_file_name` is containing `old:` as I mentioned.

Currently I'm authorized only with the new S3 bucket, not with the old one.

I have read that I should do something like:

```
    class Product
      has_attached_file: :image, url: dynamic_url_method

      def dynamic_url_method
         .... do some logic based on image_file_name
         return constructed_url
      end
    end
```

However when I do that, I get undefined local variable dynamic_url_method.

If I wrap it in a lambda as said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493048 I get `Error "no implicit conversion of Proc into String"`.

Have you guys successfully gotten Paperclip to work with a dynamic URL? It would be a life-saver if you know how to do so.

Comment: It should be a symbol: `has_attached_file: :image, url: :dynamic_url_method`, you missed the colon. What is slightly worried is that lambda should work. Could you paste the stacktrace of the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely scrap the whole idea of dynamic URL parameter given to the Paperclip attachment. It breaks S3 image uploading cause Paperclip can't figure out which URL to use.

The solution is to introduce a new column in your schema called `image_url`.
The column will be updated on initialize/update in the ActiveModel and used in the web pages.

In code

```
class Product
  has_attached_file: :image
  after_create :update_image_url
  after_update :update_image_url

  def update_image_url
     new_image_url =  # some logic based on image_file_name that would either return the CloudFront URL or save the URL from image.url which is generated by Paperclip
     # Paperclip does not update image_file_name_changed? so we can't say
     # after_create or after_update if: image_file_name_changed? instead  
     # we have to manually check that image_url and new_image_url are different
     update(image_url: new_image_url) if image_url != new_image_url
  end
end
```